# Match Two Inconsistent Lists in Excel

Tags: excel, list, sorting

I have a sort of complicated listing issue in excel and hopefully someone is up for the challenge. I appreciate any and all responses.

I have two lists of about 50,000 names. My actual workbook has longer strings of data but to keep it simple, I'll use this:

```
LIST A    LIST B
Joe       Michael
          John
Kim       Matt
Carl    
Mike      Joey
Matthew   Kimberly
```

The goal is to rearrange column B to match the appropriate nickname with column A, ie:

```
LIST A    LIST B
Joe       Joey
          John
Kim       Kimberly
Carl    
Mike      Michael
Matthew   Matt
```

The relevance of the name is less important than it matching similar characters. I can manually correct any extraneous or odd nicknames.

The other caveat is that names without akas/nicknames are left blank in the other column on both sides.

I have seen other sorting operations that could work, but don't due to the fact that the values in the two columns are technically different.

Overall - a simpler way to say is that the aim is to make them more or less stack alphabetically and then have the similar names line up and ignore things that don't match.

Let me know if any further clarification is necessary.

Thank you!

Comment: What did the `Vlookup()` using the approximate match option, give you?

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know Vlookup() could do approximations. I thought I was stuck to exact matches. I'll try it and report the results. Thanks!

Comment: It seems I'm just getting an output of 0 or #N/A. Maybe my formula is wrong? =VLOOKUP(A2,A:B,2,TRUE)

Comment: The Vlookup won't work.  You might need some form of fuzzy logic match.

Comment: try this http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/195635-fuzzy-matching-new-version-plus-explanation-3.html

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll have to do more digging in those forums